# JQuery ConnectingLine plugin not positioning line correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried using this plugin 'jquery.connectingLine.js' but my line isn't positioned correctly and its not joining as expected - [image](http://snag.gy/3Y2wq.jpg)

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.svg.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.connectingLine.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <link href="css/tmc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class='img_all'>

        <div class="img_logo1"><img src="images/img 1.png" alt="" /></div>

        <div class="img_logo2"><img src="images/img 2.png" alt="" /></div>

        <div class="img_logo3"><img src="images/img 3.png" alt="" /></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mySVG = $('body').connectSVG();
    mySVG.drawLine({
    left_node:'.img_logo1',
    right_node:'.img_logo2',
    horizantal_gap:10
    });

            $( ".img_logo1" ).draggable({
          drag: function(event, ui){mySVG.redrawLines();}
        });
        $( ".img_logo1" ).draggable({
          drag: function(event, ui){mySVG.redrawLines();}
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #001a33;
}

.img_all img{
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
}

.img_logo1 img {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 14%;
}

.img_logo2 img {
    margin-left: 74%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 14%;
}

.img_logo3 img {
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-top: 48%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally got this working - it was an oversight on my part. Where I need to reference the image files, I missed 'img' hence reason why it wasn't working. So instead of **left_node:'.img_logo1'**, it should be **left_node:'.img_logo1 img',**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mySVG = $('body').connectSVG();
mySVG.drawLine({
left_node:'.img_logo1 img',
right_node:'.img_logo2 img',
horizantal_gap:10
});

        $( ".img_logo1" ).draggable({
      drag: function(event, ui){mySVG.redrawLines();}
    });
    $( ".img_logo1" ).draggable({
      drag: function(event, ui){mySVG.redrawLines();}
    });

</script>
```